# Borrar archivo PDF luego de un redireccionamiento

Tags: php, pdf

Tengo un detalle por delante que quiero poder sortear, pero no se me ocurre como.

Tengo un código completo, que genera un archivo pdf, el cual se crea en mi servidor,
Todo funciona correctamente, y el archivo termina mostrandose al redirigir al archivo.

Para ello simplemente uso esto:

```
[...código de generación del pdf...]

$file = $rut . "_" . $nboleta . ".pdf";
$destino = "/url/del/servidor/".$file;
$pdf->Output($destino, 'F');
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=https://paginacool.cl/url/del/servidor/".$file."'>";
```

El tema es que, al redireccionar, estoy abriendo el archivo pdf en el visor del navegador.
Lo que quiero lograr es eliminar este mismo archivo pdf, con tal de que quede como un archivo temporal que solo se genere cuando se solicite el código de generacion.

He probado añadir codigo, como el uso de `unlink()` luego del `<meta>` pero nada de eso corre luego del redireccionamiento.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es que lo elimines después de mostrarlo?

Comment: yes, no se me ocurre como poder lograrlo

Comment: Habría que ver más código para saber si puedes enviarlo directamente al navegador en lugar de guardar en disco y redirigir.

Comment: A que te refieres @Triby ??

Comment: @EdgarSaavedra no leiste todo el post cierto ?

Comment: Has intentado generarlo con `$pdf->Output($destino, 'I');` para que lo muestre directo en el navegador y no lo guarde en disco. O es necesario almacenarlo?

Comment: @MRDev Eso es lo que busco, podrías formarlo como respuesta y explicar que hace i ??

Comment: @Excorpion usas FPDF?

Comment: TCPDF es el que uso

Comment: @Excorpion, el único problema sería que estés generando código HTML, no se puede mostrar contenido y descargar el archivo al mismo tiempo.

Comment: No es necesario mostrar contenido, el pdf se abre en su propio visor. Y luego puedes hacer lo que quieras en el.

Comment: ¿Entonces porque esa etiqueta `meta`?, ¿ahí termina tu script? De ser así, la sugerencia de @MRDev es correcta. Hay que esperar su respuesta.

Comment: Segun entiendo, quitando el meta, la salida de $pdf esta mostrando el archivo ya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es mostrar el PDF en el navegador sin necesidad de almacenarlo en disco puedes usar la opción "I" en la función Output para enviar el fichero al navegador de forma que se usa la extensión (plug in) si está disponible.

```
$pdf->Output($destino, 'I');
```

Con esto ya no se necesita agregar `meta` porque lo redirecciona automáticamente.

Comment: No, no necesita de meta para verlo.

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo que no se crea un archivo temporal ni se borra al cerrarlo, simplemente se envía el PDF directamente al navegador, sin involucrar creación de archivos. +1

Comment: gracias por la aclaración @Triby

Comment: Buenas MR te molesto nuevamente. Me acabo de dar cuenta que al mostrar el pdf de este modo, queda la ruta del servidor expuesta en el visor del pdf. Esto es problematico ?? No debería pasar esto creo.

Comment: @Excorpion no le veo problema si se agregan las debidas validaciones de seguridad para acceso a ese script

Comment: Como seria eso ?? Supongamos que un usuario es quien llega a pasar por el archivo de creacion, en el modo en que quedo con la respuesta, el visor pdf tiene la ruta url arriba. Si corto eso, muestra todos los archivos del servidor... eso es normal ??

Comment: Su funcionamiento es normal pero no es seguro ni recomendado, allí necesitas configurar tu servidor web para que no permite listar los archivos de las carpetas con `Options -Indexes` pero esos ya son otros temas. Te recomiendo revisar todos esos detalles y buscar sobre ello o hacer las pregunta para que se te puedan dar más detalles.

Comment: Gracias por la guia !!!